# How to analyze performance of external services?

Tags: performance, logging, analytics

I have a PHP app that collects several performance metrics of each HTTP request into a log file. These include connections to external servers, database queries and long running blocks of code. Now I've got a bunch of data I want to analyze as follows:

- Identify the slowest parts
- Graph the averaged aggregate data

I can't rely on external services like NewRelic. I can only parse the log files. At the moment I'd put the log data into a database to be able to query and use RRDTool to graph the aggregates. But this seems very "low-level" to me. Is there other software that can create aggegrate statistics and query data?

Answer (score 0):

You may find [statsd & graphite](http://mat.github.com/statsd-railscamp2011-slides/) to be a useful tool. Etsy uses this to track "low level" statistics like this:
http://codeascraft.etsy.com/2011/02/15/measure-anything-measure-everything/